# MongoDB via Mongoose JS - What is findByID?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a NodeJS server with ExpressJS, PassportJS, MongoDB and MongooseJS. I just managed to get PassportJS to use user data obtained via Mongoose to authenticate.

But to make it work, I had to use a "findById" function like below.

```
var UserModel = db.model('User',UserSchema);

UserModel.findById(id, function (err, user) { < SOME CODE > } );
```

`UserModel` is a Mongoose model. I declare the schema, `UserSchema` earlier. So I suppose `UserModel.findById()` is a method of the Mongoose model?

**Question**

What does `findById` do and is there documentation on it? I googled around a bit but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`findById` is a convenience method on the model that's provided by Mongoose to find a document by its _id. The documentation for it can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById).

Example:

```js
// Search by ObjectId
var id = "56e6dd2eb4494ed008d595bd";
UserModel.findById(id, function (err, user) { ... } );
```

Functionally, it's the same as calling:

```js
UserModel.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, user) { ... });
```

Note that Mongoose will cast the provided `id` value to the type of `_id` as defined in the schema (defaulting to ObjectId).

Comment: what's the data type of id? is it a string or an ObjectId?

Comment: @bubakazouba `id` will be cast to whatever type `_id` is defined as in the schema (defaults to `ObjectId`).

Comment: anybody know if there is a removeById convenience method as well?

Comment: @AlexanderMills There is. It is called `findByIdAndRemove`

Answer (score 9):

If the schema of id is not of type **ObjectId** you cannot operate with function :
**findbyId()**

Answer (score 7):

As opposed to find() which can return 1 or more documents,
findById() can only return 0 or 1 document.
Document(s) can be thought of as record(s).

Answer (score 4):

I'm the maintainer of Mongoose. `findById()` is a built-in method on Mongoose models. `findById(id)` is equivalent to `findOne({ _id: id })`, with one caveat: `findById()` with 0 params is equivalent to `findOne({ _id: null })`.

You can read more about [`findById()` on the Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) and [this `findById()` tutorial](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/find-by-id).

Comment: I am getting the following error:
`{
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ id: '5d9a3b073f308e32b47a5cbb' }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Categories\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "stringValue": "\"{ id: '5d9a3b073f308e32b47a5cbb' }\"",
  "kind": "ObjectId",
  "value": {
    "id": "5d9a3b073f308e32b47a5cbb"
  },
  "path": "_id"
}`

Comment: Looks like you're passing in an object with an `id` property rather than a string or ObjectId instance. Try printing out `typeof val` and `val.constructor.name` to check what type you're actually passing in to `findById()`

Comment: I tried many combinations. Or may I say, all combinations. I do no have a property named `id`. I do no have the property of type `ObjectId`.

Comment: ok. found out my mistake. it was a silly one. i was passing id object as { id: 'blablabla' } instead of string...

Comment: @vkarpov15 Where can I find source of this `findById`?