# im trying to pull the current user's data only from my mongodb to use in ejs file for a profile route where it should be custom to each user's inputs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs, body-parser

want this to render the currentusers user.object

```
app.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, (req,res)=>{
User.find({}, (err,User)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/login");
    }else{
        res.render("pages/userprofile", {User:User});
        console.log(User);
    }
})
});
```

this is my user schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
review: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Review"
}
});
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

when i run the code going to the profile route, it brings back all the users and I have tried multiple ways to only bring back one but I keep getting error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB via Mongoose JS - What is findByID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483632/mongodb-via-mongoose-js-what-is-findbyid)

Comment: Use a tool such as Grammarly to improve your writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using `findById(id)` since the Mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) suggested to use it than `findOne({ _id: id })`.

```
app.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.user, (err, User) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/login");
    } else {

      res.render("pages/userprofile", { User: User });
      console.log(User);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `findOne` for getting one user.

```
app.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, (req,res)=>{
    User.findOne({}, (err,User)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/login");
        }else{
            res.render("pages/userprofile", {User:User});
            console.log(User);
        }
    })
    });
```

Comment: I've tried that but its not grabbing the current user in session I have figured out how to grab the current user using.                         User.find({_id: req.user}.... but for some reason in my ejs file when I do <%= User.username%> username comes back undefined which is odd because i have another mongoose schema that is nearly identical and it can pull username no problem

Comment: im wondering if I can't access it because it has passport plugin.. for now im going to go make a new profile schema and see if I can use User as a reference and be able to grab the username that way will post updates

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, (req,res)=>{
User.findOne({_id: req.user}, (err,User)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/login");
    }else{
        
        res.render("pages/userprofile", {User:User});
        console.log(User);
    }
})
});
```

I tried the findOne({...}... and it worked!!!! thank you for the help