# Mongoose findBiId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a real estate project. The property's model is:

```
const propertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    secondAddress: String,
    city: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    zip: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
});
```

When I try to get the information of a specific property I get the error `Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer`. If I hardcode the id everything works. The route to get to the property is:

```
router.get('/property/:id', async(req, res) => {
    const property = await Property.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('pages/user/property', { property })
})
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You need `_id` in your schema in order to use `findById`, but you don't have one.
See documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById),
and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483632/mongodb-via-mongoose-js-what-is-findbyid) by JohnnyHK

Comment: The _id Is created by mongodb

Comment: yes, but this is a mongoose implementation